# improve performance in business application

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, reporting-services, triggers

I'm doing a business application in C# windows form. 
About 10000 data entry per day.

current implementation for After Triggers:

```
1. Filter relevant data from the base table and insert to the secondary table
2. Send email to users when there is an insert/delete/update to the secondary table.
3. exec stored procedure when there is an insert/delete/update to the secondary table.
```

one of the problem is sometimes there is a deadlock when display report in SSRS

Click one deployment
current implementation is manual installation. no online update
should have use file share to deploy it so can check for updates

any can advice should I use triggers for business application

Comment: This shouldn't be such a problem you can use a "with(no lock)" statement in your ssrs report if you frequently call huge data while users are working on your data

Answer (score 0):

1.) I am not in favour of using triggers to implement business logic. As it is difficult to maintain BL in the triggers.

2.) I have seen the trigger do not fire on each record if you are updating bulk records.

3.) To troubleshoot the performance issue you can turn on the SQL Profiler to get a trace files. In that trace file you can analyse where is the deadlock.

4.) There are ready made DMV queries available on the net to a.) get a list of top slow queries. b.) unused indexes (you can remove these indexes) c.) missed indexes (you can add new indexes) d.) Indexes that needs to add/drop columns and many more.

4.) You can apply nolock query hint on reports queries to gain performance.

5.) If everything is fine then you should look into the RDL. Rendering sometimes also consume a lot of time depending upon the functions used in the rdl.